# Fill in the blank: "I say this with no _____ of pride" (Answer was "modicum")

Tags: single-word-requests, greek

To help make this all make sense, there is a word I am looking for--I can hear it in my mind and I can say it with my lips. But I can find no source.

The phrase I hear is, "I say this with no monocomb of pride." The way I understand it is, along the lines of, "I say this without an ounce of pride," or "one bit of pride."

---

UPDATE:

I looked up the greek word for *bit* at random and found it to be kommati, so I did variations of this and came up with modicum.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for, o' dear me, is "modicum."

Comment: This answer is the right one, but you should provide a link to a dictionary definition along with a quotation of it.

Comment: @JasonBassford But isn't "modicum" (a small amount) normally used in the positive? I think of putting "a modicum of garlic in the dish". I could understand "...with a modicum of pride", which may be what the speaker meant. But what does "...with NO modicum of pride" mean - presumably "a great deal of pride"? And that is completely contrary to what the OP is thinking, when he says "without an ounce of pride".

Comment: @ws2 Ah, yes. I just noticed this with your comment. Alas, the questioner is confused. The word that couldn't be remembered is definitely [modicum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modicum). Unfortunately, the phrase has been understood in the opposite sense. (It's the double negative that's tripping things up.) [*A modicum of pride.*](https://ludwig.guru/s/modicum+of+pride)